# Disproving Differentiable Functions with Counter Examples

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, examples-counterexamples, chain-rule

How do I find the counter example for...

If a function $g$ is differentiable at $a$ and a function $f$ is not differentiable at $g(a)$, then the function $f \circ g$ cannot be differentiable at $a$.

Comment: Try something simple, like $f(x)=|x|$, $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=x^2$.  $g$ is differentiable at $0$ but $f$ is not.  On the other hand, $(f\circ g)(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Wouldn't (f of g)(x) = |x^2|? Or is x^2 the same as |x^2|?

Comment: Since $x^2$ is always non-negative, $|x^2|=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial example: $g(x)=b$ and $f(x)=$'anything defined at $b$ with discontinuity at $b$'.